# Alignment of markdown table for Beamer slides created from Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, beamer

I was having trouble compiling some old Rmardkown beamer slides that included markdown tables. I followed the recommendations [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/625). They now compile but the alignment of the contents does not follow the alignment of the column titles.

The warning messages suggest to rerun LaTeX. When I knit the document a second time I get the same result.

Rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
## Slide with Table

| number | letter |
|---|---|
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b c d e f g h i|
| 3 | j |
````

Messages:

```
Warning message:
Package longtable Warning: Column widths have changed
(longtable)                in table 1 on input line 119.
Package longtable Warning: Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX.
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you add more hyphens than 3 (e.g. 10 hyphens in each column)? I think you can widen columns by increasing numbers of the character.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera does not seem to have an effect

Comment: Sorry for my vain suggestion; actually, I failed to produce the well-formed PDF, too... However, I achieved [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839468/10215301). Please check it out and I hope the answer will help you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in https://rstudio.cloud/project/676736 Maybe a version problem?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163706/169454) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74684/169454) in TeX.se, you need to rerun LaTeX; and **this is totally different operation from knitting multiple times by pressing the `knit` button or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> on Windows OS/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> on Mac**.

## 1. Knit the `.Rmd` file with `keep_tex: true` option

In order to rerun LaTeX, be sure to get `.tex` file by setting `keep_tex: yes`. If you knit the following `.Rmd` file, say `test.Rmd`, you would obtain `test.pdf` and `test.tex`. In this phase, your PDF file shows ill-formed table.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: yes
#The following `output` option produces a beamer presentation with more flexibility    
#output:
#  bookdown::pdf_book:
#    base_format: "function(..., number_sections) rmarkdown::beamer_presentation(...)"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with Table

<!-- https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables -->

| number | letter |
|---|---|
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b c d e f g h i |
| 3 | j |

  : Original Table
````

## 2. Run `latexmk` in Terminal

In RStudio, you will find `Terminal` tab at the bottom left corner (i.e. RStudio's console), as shown below:

[image: <code>Terminal</code> tab at the bottom left corner]

If you have already installed [latexmk](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/software/latexmk/) in your computer, just type the code below on the `Terminal` tab of the RStudio.

```
latexmk test.tex -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode
```

This means:

> *Hey, `latexmk`, process `test.tex` using `pdflatex` engine without any pause (`-interaction=nonstopmode`)*.

Then, your `test.tex` would be processed multiple times until the desirable PDF file, like the one which the following image demonstrates, is produced.

[image]